# Google Analytics Data different from API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When I query certain data from Google Analytics I get different data than when I manually lookup the data in Google Analytics. The filters and segments are the same on both.

[The Google Dev Query and Google Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgPoy.png)

What might cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your report from API contains sampled data:

> Contains sampled data: **Yes**

Try to type `HIGHER_PRECISION` in the `samplingLevel` field. Or decrease your date range.